# Can a Pokémon attack more than once per turn?

Tags: pokemon

[Mewtwo-Ex](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/pokemon-cards/xy-series/xy12/52/) has an ability called Energy Absorption, which costs one colorless energy to activate:

> Attach an Energy card from your discard pile to this Pokémon.

So, say I start my turn with two energy attached to my Mewtwo-Ex.  Can I then activate this attack twice, and put two energy from my discard pile onto my Mewtwo-Ex in one turn?

If so, can I then turn this into a loop, and place every energy from my discard pile onto my Mewtwo in a single turn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [official Pokémon TCG rulebook](https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokemon-tcg/rules):

> Once you attack, your turn is over (…)!

Pokémon TCG is a round-based game (just like Nintendo games) so you only get one attack as the last step of your turn. Even though you have enough energy to use an attack twice or to use two different attacks, you still need to choose only one attack and use it only once.

Comment: You know, this is all so obvious now in hindsight.  My son (who taught me) had been playing multiple attacks, so I was just confused.  My son could never be wrong!  Thanks.